# How to add a saving function/button in c#?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, save

I made a note taking app in VS using **C# and windows forms**, but the save button only adds the "note" to the **DataGridView** I added to display the title and message of the "note", so when you close the application **it deletes everything you wrote**. I want to change it so when you close the app it **actually saves all of your notes and restores them as they were.** Can anybody help?

I looked it up but all I saw were **SQL databases and tables**, so since I'm quite new to programming I don't understand anything of that. And the explanations of those are also pretty crap. At least the ones I found.

Comment: Please post code for what you have tried so far. [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This will help with good suggestions for how to write your data to disk ("serialize" it) and read it the next time you open the app.

Comment: you need to do object serialization on closes app to save all the object states to database before closing the app?

Comment: You need a way to store the data onto disk (for example on in a plaintext txt file, CSV or a database) and then reload them when the program opens. Do some research into saving to a file, there is a lot of useful documentation/tutorials around that area for beginners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataGridView` will do most of the work if you attach your list of notes to its `DataSource` property. This list will be easily convertible to a format (Json) that can be written to disk and the DGV will give you events that will trigger the saves (no button required). So, first make a class that has the public properties of a `Note`:

```
class Note
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

---

Next, make the `BindingList` to hold some `Note` objects.

```
BindingList<Note> Notes = new BindingList<Note>();
```

---

When the `MainForm` loads, we'll assign the `DataSource`, generate columns, and if there is already a saved `notes.json` file we can load it back in here. Call the `save` method whenever a Cell is done editing or when a row is removed.

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);

    dataGridView.DataSource = Notes;

    // Generate columns
    Notes.Add(new Note());
    dataGridView.Columns[nameof(Note.Title)].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
    dataGridView.Columns[nameof(Note.Message)].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
    Notes.Clear();

    // Read in the saved notes from last time.
    if (File.Exists(_jsonPath))
    {
        var json = File.ReadAllText(_jsonPath);
        var saved = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Note[]>(json);
        foreach (var note in saved)
        {
            Notes.Add(note);
        }
    }

    // Actions that trigger a save
    dataGridView.CellEndEdit += (sender, e) => save();
    dataGridView.RowsRemoved += (sender, e) => save();
}
```

Here's the DGV after manually typing in the first Note:

[image: screenshot]

---

One way to save `Notes` is to write it as a Json file. (Make sure you have installed the `Newtonsoft.Json` NuGet and are `using System.Linq` and  `using Newtonsoft.Json`).

```
private void save()
{
    // Do not block on this method
    BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate 
    {
        // Don't save a note if both fields are null.
        var onlyValidNotes = Notes.Where(_ => !(
            string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_.Title) &&
            string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_.Message)));
        File.WriteAllText(
            _jsonPath, 
            JsonConvert.SerializeObject(onlyValidNotes, Formatting.Indented));
    });
}
```

---

And where do we save the data? One good choice is the user's local AppData file for this application. We can set this path in the MainForm CTor:

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // Create a file path to persist the data.
    var appDataFolder = Path.Combine(
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData),
        GetType().Assembly.GetName().Name
    );
    Directory.CreateDirectory(appDataFolder);
    _jsonPath = Path.Combine(appDataFolder, "notes.json");
}
readonly string _jsonPath;
```

Comment: I didn't want to mess with an accepted answer, but it occurs to me that `Task.Run` should probably be used instead of `BeginInvoke` so that the save isn't happening on the UI thread. This minor change has been committed to the [repo](https://github.com/IVSoftware/data-grid-view-simple-serialization.git) for reference.